# Putting contributions of continuous values in a discrete 2D grid, based on distance from the nearest pixels

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation, data-analysis, bilinear-interpolation

I have a numpy array containing coordinates of points (in 3D, but I am have started off by trying the method in 1D and 2D first) that I would like to fit in a discrete grid. However, I do not want to just move the points to the grid pixel which they are closest to, but rather put on each pixel a weighted value which depends on how far from that pixel the point actually is. For example, if in 1D I have a point x = 15.4, in my discrete space this point would contribute 60% to pixel 15 and 40% to pixel 16. I have managed to do this in 1D and the code is as follows:

```py
# Make test data

N = 1000

data = np.random.normal(
    loc = 10,
    scale = 2,
    size = N
)

# set data range, binsize, and coordinates
xmin = 0
xmax = 20
xbinsize = 0.5

# define the bin centres
xbincenters = np.arange(
    xmin+xbinsize*0.5,
    xmax,
    xbinsize
)

# transform data and floor it to get the closest pixel in the discrete grid
data_t = data/xbinsize - 0.5
bin_indices = np.floor(data_t).astype(int)
# calculate the difference between continuous coordinate and closest pixel
dx = data_t - bin_indices

# get data range in bin indices

index_min = np.ceil(xmin/xbinsize - 0.5).astype(int)
index_max = np.ceil(xmax/xbinsize - 0.5).astype(int)

# do the interpolation

minlength = index_max - index_min

output_array = np.bincount(
    bin_indices,
    weights = (1-dx),
    minlength = minlength
) +\
np.bincount(
    bin_indices+1,
    weights = dx,
    minlength = minlength
)

# finally plot a histogram of the continuous values against output_array
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(data, bins=np.arange(0,20,0.5))
ax.plot(
    xbincenters,
    output_array,
    color = 'r'
)
plt.show()
```

[comparison plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXk3d.png)

I have been trying to generalise this to 2D but to no avail, since `np.bincount()` only works on 1D arrays.

Up until trying to find the nearest pixels, I feel like the code should be similar, as all the operations above can be broadcasted to a 2D array. In this case, we need to distribute any coordinate to the nearest 4 pixels, depending on a difference `dx` and now another difference `dy` (which, if you used the above code for an array of shape `(1000, 2)` would just be the 1st and second column of the array `dx` respectively). I tried unraveling my `bin_indices` and `dx` arrays to use `np.bincount()` on them, but at this point I am not sure if that is correct or what operations to do on the unraveled arrays. Would generalising this problem in 2D (and later in 3D) need a different kind of approach? Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I get it correctly, you did "by hand" all the interpolation job (there are probably some code to do that somewhere, but can't think of any right now), and use `bincount` just to increase the output array (because `output_array[indices] += weight` wouldn't have worked, indeed, if indices contain repetitions)

Then, you could just modify indices to target yourself a  2D arrays. Using a width and a height, and using `indicesy*width+indicesx` as indices. And then "unravel" the array once finished.

Like this

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 1000

# Big array for performance test
datax = np.random.normal(
    loc = 10,
    scale = 2,
    size = N
)
datay = np.random.normal(
    loc = 10,
    scale = 2,
    size = N
)

# Or small one for result test (comment if not wanted)
datax = np.array([15.2, 1.5, 15.3])
datay = np.array([5.1, 10.5, 15.9])


# set data range, binsize, and coordinates
xmin = 0
xmax = 20
xbinsize = 0.5
ymin = 0
ymax = 20
ybinsize = 0.5

# define the bin centres
xbincenters = np.arange(
    xmin+xbinsize*0.5,
    xmax,
    xbinsize
)
ybincenters = np.arange(
    ymin+ybinsize*0.5,
    ymax,
    ybinsize
)

# transform data and floor it to get the closest pixel in the discrete grid
datax_t = datax/xbinsize - 0.5
datay_t = datay/ybinsize - 0.5
bin_indicesx = np.floor(datax_t).astype(int)
bin_indicesy = np.floor(datay_t).astype(int)
# calculate the difference between continuous coordinate and closest pixel
dx = datax_t - bin_indicesx
dy = datay_t - bin_indicesy

# get data range in bin indices

index_minx = np.ceil(xmin/xbinsize - 0.5).astype(int)
index_miny = np.ceil(ymin/ybinsize - 0.5).astype(int)
index_maxx = np.ceil(xmax/xbinsize - 0.5).astype(int)
index_maxy = np.ceil(ymax/ybinsize - 0.5).astype(int)

# do the interpolation

minlengthx = index_maxx - index_minx
minlengthy = index_maxy - index_miny
minlength=minlengthx*minlengthy

flat_output_array = np.bincount(
    bin_indicesy*minlengthx+bin_indicesx,
    weights = (1-dx)*(1-dy),
    minlength = minlength
) +\
np.bincount(
    bin_indicesy*minlengthx+bin_indicesx+1,
    weights = dx*(1-dy),
    minlength = minlength
) +\
np.bincount(
    (bin_indicesy+1)*minlengthx+bin_indicesx,
    weights = (1-dx)*dy,
    minlength = minlength
) +\
np.bincount(
    (bin_indicesy+1)*minlengthx+bin_indicesx+1,
    weights = dx*dy,
    minlength = minlength
) 

output_array=flat_output_array.reshape(-1, minlengthx)

# finally plot a histogram of the continuous values against output_array
plt.imshow(output_array)

plt.show()
```

[image: 3 points]

[image: 1000 normal distribution points]

Comment: I ran the code but it doesn't produce the second picture which is meant to be the output, instead showing the first plot as the output

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it seems that it works very well! Could you please explain the reasoning behind using `indicesy*width+indicesx` as indices?

Comment: @OM222O Well, there are two sets of `datax/datay` in the code. The first one (1000 points) produce the second plot. The second one (3 points) produces the first one. If you don't comment the second one, it prevails. If you do, then you get the second plot. See comment in the code.

Comment: @CrystalMath. It is a way to "flatten" the array. `flat_output_array` is a len `width*height` 1D array (in the code, I use variables names as close as possible as yours, so that is `minlengthx*minlengthy`). That contains the values of a width x height 2D arrays. So, storing data in the "natural order" (also called "C" order in numpy), that is each line after the other, value at `(indicex, indicey)` in that 2D `widthxheight` 2D-array is the `indicey x width + indicex`th value in that array (so in the len `widthxheight` 1D array).

Comment: @CrystalMath. Maybe it is easier with an example. If you have 3 lines (3 indices in axis y) of 4 columns (4 indices in axis x), then the output array is a 3x4 2D array. That is 12 values. That yoiu can represent by a 1D "flatten output array" of 12 values (v00, v01, v02, v03, v11, v12, v13, v14, v20, v21, v22, v23, v34; vyx being value at line y column x). If you want to add 1 to value matching `indicey=2, indicex=1`, that is v21, that is the 4x2+1th value (starting at the 0th value) of the 1D array. So index 9 in the 1D array (and indeed if you start counting at 0, then v21 it the 9th value)

Comment: In 3D, you would need to replace that by a 1D len `minlengthx*minlengthy*minlengthz` array. And value at index `(bin_indicex, bin_indicey, bin_indicez)` in the 3D output would be the value at index `minlengthx*minlengthy*bin_indicez + minlengthx*bin_indicey + bin_indicex`)